# Llamar a una clase

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un buscador que tiene 2 clases el problema es para mandar a llamar a estas clases que estan dentro de la clase Buscador me marca error; probe por separado mis clases, estan bien

```
package buscador;

public class Buscador {
public class Buscador_secuencial<E extends Comparable<E>> {
     private E[] b;
  public Buscador_secuencial(E [] palabras){
              b = palabras;
   }
   public int busca(Comparable<E> v) {
         int posicion = -1;
  for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){    //recorremos todo el arreglo
     if(b[i] == v){   //comparamos el elemento en el arreglo con el buscado
         posicion = i;   //Si es verdadero guardamos la posicion
    break;     //Para el ciclo
    }
   }
return posicion;
   }
}

public class Buscador_binario<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private E[] a;

    public Buscador_binario(E[] palabras) {
        a = palabras;
    }

    public int buscar(Comparable<E> v) {
        int bajo = 0;
        int alto = a.length - 1;

        while (bajo <= alto) {
            int med = (bajo + alto) / 2;
            E medVal = a[med];
            int resultado = v.compareTo(medVal);

            if (resultado < 0) {
                alto = med - 1;
            }

            else if (resultado > 0) {
                bajo = med + 1;
            } 

            else {
                return med;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


package buscador;



public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] palabras = {"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", 
            "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliet", "Kilo", "Lima", 
            "Mike", "Noviembre", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", 
            "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "X-Ray", 
            "Yankee", "Zulu"};

        Buscador.Buscador_secuencial <String>Buscador = new Buscador_secuencial<String>(palabras);
        System.out.println("Posicion de la palabra:   "+Buscador.busca("Juliet"));
        System.out.println("Si esta en la lista\n");

        System.out.println("Posicion de la palabra:   "+Buscador.busca("Octubre"));
        System.out.println("La palabra no esta en la lista");


        Buscador.Buscador_binario <String>Buscado = new Buscador_binario<String>(palabras);
        System.out.println("Posicion de la palabra:   "+Buscado.buscar("Juliet"));
        System.out.println("Si esta en la lista\n");

        System.out.println("Posicion de la palabra:   "+Buscado.buscar("Octubre"));
        System.out.println("La palabra no esta en la lista");




    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1):

Estas creando una nueva instancia de Buscador_secuencial , pero esta clase esta dentro de Buscador, por tanto debes instanciar primero la `clase Buscador` y seguido por un punto la `clase Buscador_secuencial`, osea asi: `new  Buscador().new Buscador_secuencial<String>(palabras);`

> Los errores se presenta aquí:

```
Buscador.Buscador_secuencial <String>Buscador = new Buscador_secuencial<String>(palabras);

Buscador.Buscador_binario <String>Buscado = new Buscador_binario<String>(palabras);
```

> y deberia ser de esta forma:

```
Buscador.Buscador_secuencial <String>Buscador = new  Buscador().new Buscador_secuencial<String>(palabras);

Buscador.Buscador_binario <String>Buscado = new  Buscador().new Buscador_binario<String>(palabras);
```

Comment: Te agradezco por tomarte el tiempo de responder mi pregunta, ya lo corregí y corre perfectamente, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si ter sirvió marca como resuelta la pregunta. Estamos para ayudar